# Probability with replacement - Red AND green marbles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, problem-solving

You have a bag with five different colored marbles in it; red, green, blue, orange, and purple. Each marble has an equal chance of being drawn from the bag and a marble is replaced after each draw. After four draws from the bag what is the probability that you have seen both the red and green marble?

I initially thought it would be 1- (3/5)^4 but that is the answer for Red OR Green. I am kinda stumped on how to set this problem up to solve it via PIE. Could somebody please  solve the question or walk me through it. Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Is the marble replaced with the one of the same color?

Comment: Yes they are replaced with one of the same color

Comment: Hint: each sequence of $5$ colors is equally probable so you just need to count the good sequences.  Use Inclusion exclusion.

Comment: Probability of Red =  1 - (4/5)^4 = 369/625

Probability of Green = 1 - (4/5)^4 = 369/625

Probability of  Red or Green = 1 - (3/5)^4 = 544/625

Probability of Red and Green =  (369+369 -544)/625 = 194/625

Would this be right?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is clearer with sequences.  There are $5^4$ sequences with no restriction, $4^4$ that omit a particular color, $3^4$ that omit two specific colors, hence there are $5^4-4^4-4^4+3^4$ sequences that contain both of two specific colors, now just divide by $5^4$.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you for your assistance.